# Path to WordPress Template Directory inside jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My header is calling a javascript file which sends out an email:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/css/effects.js"></script>
```

But inside this file, I have a jQuery code that calls a .php file that does the actual sending of the email:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "css/sendmail.php",
  data: dataString`
```

But the script doesn't work, unless the url is:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/css/sendmail.php
```

and not just:

```
css/sendmail.php
```

Is there any way to include a path to the wordpress template directory inside js?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could create a Javascript snippet that saves the template dir in a variable, and use this later:

```
<script>
var templateDir = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: how to use var templateDir another string?