# Adding Lightbox to wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, lightbox

I need to add lightbox to a theme instead of using the plugin. I added it and everything works fine but for some reason close.png and loading.gif images keeps referring to site.com/images/close.png . My lightbox.js is in themes/mytheme/libs and images are in themes/mytheme/images . I have changed lightbox.js as following .

```
 this.fileLoadingImage = '../images/loading.gif';
  this.fileCloseImage = '../images/close.png';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are needing to include the full path in your lightbox.js file one way to do it is to follow this example -> [Path to WordPress Template Directory inside jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856600/path-to-wordpress-template-directory-inside-jquery)

You would set the value of a variable to the Wordpress template directory in your header.php prior to the inclusion of lightbox.js and then use that variable to produce an absolute path;

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var templateDir = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>";
 </script>
```