# Javascript: Get full path to a directory

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lightbox

I'm using lightbox with a WordPress theme. It has defined some images path in the lightbox.js file. For example

```
this.fileLoadingImage = '/images/lb-loading.gif';
```

So if I change the above path to following to get the images from the theme directory:

```
this.fileLoadingImage = 'wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/lb-loading.gif';
```

It will work on homepage only. But it won't work on other pages. This the above path is not valid on the other pages. So how can I get the full path to the image directory dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image to be seen on all pages, you must use an absolute path. Try adding a `/` before `wp-content` like so:

```
this.fileLoadingImage = '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/lb-loading.gif';
```

Comment: This will depend on Wordpress running at the "root" of the domain, and should obviously be adapted if you're running it under `http://example.com/subfolder` (`/subfolder/wp-content/...`) -- if you want THAT part to be figured out automatically, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856600/path-to-wordpress-template-directory-inside-jquery